# Como esticar um form somente a largura?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Queria saber como esticar um form somente para direita ou para esquerda impedindo de esticar para baixo e para cima.

Verifiquei no site [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.BorderStyle) quem os formulários têm essa propriedade mais não me atende por completo.

```
Valor           Significado
bsDialog      - Não redimensionável; sem menu minimizar / maximizar
bsSingle      - Não redimensionável; menu minimizar / maximizar
bsNone        - Não redimensionável; nenhuma linha de fronteira visível
bsSizeable    - Borda redimensionável padrão
bsToolWindow  - Como bsSingle, mas com uma legenda menor
bsSizeToolWin - Como bsSizeable com uma legenda menor
```

A opção `bsSizeable` até me atende mais permite esticar também para cima e para baixo.
se algum souber como impedir o usuário de esticar para cima ou para baixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade Constraints.MaxWidth e MinWidth para limitar as dimensões.

Comment: Poxa! Ficou muito bom. 
Nunca me atentei para essa propriedade.

Comment: Sim, muito bom mesmo. Com essa propriedade, dá prá implementar o controle de tamanho "antes" do redimensionamento. Bem melhor que tratar no OnResize, que ocorre após o redimensionamento.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode programar um limitador no evento 'OnResize', penso em algo como:

```
  if Self.Height <> 400 then
    Self.Height := 400;
```

E isto serviria para qualquer estilo do form. Neste exemplo estamos limitando qualquer redimensionamento para cima ou para baixo.